# ElasticSearch: Having to loop over a script score query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Hej, I'm developing a small service to calculate similarities between items. I have ingested data into an index in ElasticSearch cluster where each item is represented by a numerical vector of dimension `d`together with an `id`. I've developed a function where you input a list of ids and then the ElasticSearch computes the most similar items to those items. However, in my query I have to loop over each document/item to extract the numerical vector.
Is there anyway I can make this more efficient, so I don't have to query ElasticSearch in a loop in python?

```
def query_es_for_similar_items(es: Elasticsearch, item_ids: List[int], index: str, n=100):
    query1 = {"query": {"ids": {"type": "_doc", "values": item_ids}}}
    documents = es.search(index=index, body=query1)
    d_res = dict()
    for document in documents["hits"]["hits"]:
        item_id = int(document["_id"])
        query = {
            "size": n,
            "query": {
                "script_score": {
                    "query": {"bool": {"must_not": [{"match": {"_id": item_id}}]}},
                    "script": {
                        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field]) + 1",
                        "params": {
                            "field": "embeddings",
                            "query_value": document["_source"]["embeddings"],
                        },
                    },
                }
            },
        }
        resp = es.search(index=index, body=query)
        ranked_scores = [
            {
                "item_id": document["_id"],
                "similarity": document["_score"] / 2,
            }
            for document in resp["hits"]["hits"]
        ]
        d_res[item_id] = ranked_scores
    return d_res
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `filter` in your script score query body and retrieve its `_score` in the response body you get from Elasticsearch.

```
def query_es_for_similar_items(es: Elasticsearch, item_ids: List[int], index: str, n=100):
    query = {
       "script_score": 
                "query": 
                    {"bool": {"must_not": [{"match": {"_id": item_id}}]},
                     "filter": {"ids": {"values": item_ids}},
                    "script": {
                        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field]) + 1",
                        "params": {
                            "field": "embeddings",
                            "query_value": document["_source"]["embeddings"],
                        },
                    },
                }
            },
        }
    documents = es.search(index=index, body=query, size=n)
    d_res = dict()
    for document in documents["hits"]["hits"]:
        item_id = int(document["_id"])
        
        ranked_scores = int(document["_score"]) / 2
        d_res[item_id] = ranked_scores
    return d_res
```

Do let me know if the above solution worked for you (am using Elasticsearch 8.4.1). Cheers.